# using next iterator to add to class list

Tags: python, iterator

I am a little confused as to why this code works the first time, but on subsequent calls - the next returns a bool rather than either the object from the list or raise the exception.
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)

```
class report:
    title="Sample title"
    def __init__(self,rundate,runuser=""):
        self.rundate = rundate
        self.user = runuser
        self.systems = []

    def addNodeReport(self,systemname,reponame,nodename,result):
        try:
            sys = next(x.name == systemname for x in self.systems)
        except StopIteration:
            sys = system(systemname) # additional class
            self.systems.append(sys)
        finally:
            print sys # added for testing
            sys.addReport(reponame,nodename,result)
```

---

```
>>> from report import report
>>> r = report("20151127")
>>> r.addNodeReport("testsystem1","scripts","testhost1","All fine")
<report.system instance at 0x1c5b908>
>>> r.addNodeReport("testsystem1","scripts","testhost2","All fine")
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "report.py", line 44, in addNodeReport
    sys.addReport(reponame,nodename,result)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'addReport'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read about generator expressions, it isn't going to work as you want.

During the first run `sys = next(x.name == systemname for x in self.systems)` immediately fails with `StopIteration` because `self.systems` is empty. In the `except` section sys is assigned a `report.system` object.

During the second run `sys = next(x.name == systemname for x in self.systems)` evaluates to `sys = True` because this is exactly what generators do.

```
sys = next(x.name == systemname for x in self.systems)
# is equivalent to
if self.systems:
    x = self.systems[0]  # next function takes the first value of the list
    sys = (x.name == systemname)  # here sys becomes a boolean value
else:
    raise StopIteration
```

So basically `x.name == systemname for x in self.systems` creates a generator that yields `True` or `False` each time you call `next` upon it. (or `next` is implicitly called for instance in `for in` loop)

If you want to take all systems with name `systemname`, use `filter`:

```
systems = filter(lambda x: x.name == systemname, self.systems)
for sys in systems:
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Thanks - I was atempting not to have to access the list elements via a for loop or index as the list should only have one systemname.

Comment: @Enchanterkeiby if you're sure that `self.systems` has 0 or 1 element all the time it's better to have `self.system` member that contains a system object or `None`.

Comment: self.systems will contain many objects but only 0 or 1 that match systemname `sys = filter(lambda x: x.name == systemname, self.systems)  if sys: do_stuff(sys[0])  else:   create new sys and do stuff ` seems messy

Comment: @Enchanterkeiby well, then just do `systems[0]` instead of looping and catch an `IndexError`